# Reading a character in python using readchar package

Tags: python, key

I'm trying to read a character in python so that to perform an action based on the input. I understood there is no easy way to read key strokes in python with the help of Google. I finally found **'readchar'** package which is promising but I was not able to make it work in a simple program. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    import readchar

    def keyprint():
        while True:
            print "Press 'A' to Start the recording"
            print "      'Z' to Stop the recording"
            print "      'Enter' to quit the program..."

            # Read a key
            key = readchar.readkey()
            if(key == 'A'):
                print "Started Recording..."
            elif(key == 'Z'):
                print "Stopped Recording..."
            elif(key == '\r'):
                print "Exiting..."
                break
            else:
                print "Please Use only allowed keys: A, Z, Enter!" 

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        keyprint()
```

EDIT: Output Error

```
File "/home/inblueswithu/Documents/LM_DataCollection/keystroke_test.py", line 22, in <module>
  keyprint()
File "/home/inblueswithu/Documents/LM_DataCollection/keystroke_test.py", line 10, in keyprint
  key = readchar.readkey()
File "/home/inblueswithu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/readchar/readchar.py", line 20, in readkey
  c1 = getchar()
File "/home/inblueswithu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/readchar/readchar_linux.py", line 12, in readchar
  old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)

termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
```

Thanks,
inblueswithu

Comment: what are you getting as your key?

Comment: @RNar Sorry, forgot to add the original error message! Now edited the question.

Comment: that doesn't look like a problem with your code, that traceback looks like a problem with the library... also, why dont you just use `raw_input`?

Comment: @RNar Thanks a lot for the workaround. 1. I'm new to python and I didn't know the `raw_input` method. 
2. I tested it, it works very close to what I wanted but I need to press 'Enter' key after any input. I need it to be instantaneous, like soon after pressing the key. 
3. Yes, the trace actually goes back to the readchar package here : https://github.com/magmax/python-readchar I opened an issue in there as well

Comment: ah in that case, there is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user that uses` Getch`

Comment: Infact I found readchar package from that page in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25342814/815539 . This looked like the easiest of them all. Probably I should try the other methods..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After discussing this issue on github with the creator of the project - magmax ([here](https://github.com/magmax/python-readchar/issues/11#issuecomment-151014538)), I understood that `readchar` package works only if you try to run it from a terminal but not from any IDE or other non terminal executions. The error is caused because it tries to get the terminal settings which is non existent in this case.

I have been trying to run it from an Wing IDE. The program works great if you try to run it from a terminal.

P.S: magmax suggested to use `readchar.keys.ENTER` instead of `\r` . And suggested to have a look at https://github.com/magmax/python-inquirer & [its examples](http://python-inquirer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the word '**key**' to put your input in,  use something like "k". The Readchar module uses the word 'key' in its routine.

```
            k = readchar.readkey()
            if(k == 'A'): etc etc
```